# Removing vertical lines/formatting for a specific table row

Tags: tables

I want to remove any vertical lines (or any formatting) for the last row of this table. Any tips on how to do this would be great!

```
begin{tabular}{||c c||} \\ 
\hline
Event & P(Event) \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline\hline
A=1 & 3/10 \\ 
\hline
B=1 & 3/10 \\
\hline
A=1\text{ and }B=1 & 1/10 \\
\hline
\\
$P(A=1)P(B=1)$ & 9/100
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Where do you see a vertical line or a formatting in your snippet?

Comment: examples should be a complete document but you have not even shown a complete table or any vertical lines, so how can we know want to remove? (there should be no `\\ ` after the `\hline`)

Comment: presumably `\multicolumn{1}{c}{$P(A=1)P(B=1)$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{9/100}\\ `

Comment: @Bernard apologies I realized my formatting was wrong (new SX user struggles). There are double lines on the outside of each row currently

Comment: @DavidCarlisle apologies, I fixed the formatting now. Will try out your suggestion

Comment: the comment above is the answer but please in future always posy complete documents so people can run them to see the issue.  even after your edit you have only posted a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\multicolumn{1}` to specify different formatting for a cell, here `c` rather than `||c` so:

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$P(A=1)P(B=1)$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{9/100}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, your suggestion above was great.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 4.0), you will have by default the same tabular. However, you will have an option `last-row`. With that key, the vertical rules won't be drawn in the last row (nevertheless, other formatting will remain).

You may need two compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{||CC||}[last-row] 
\hline
Event & P(Event) \\[0.5ex] 
\hline\hline
A=1 & 3/10 \\ 
\hline
B=1 & 3/10 \\
\hline
A=1\text{ and }B=1 & 1/10 \\
\hline
$P(A=1)P(B=1)$ & 9/100
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: In this answer, since version 5.0 of `nicematrix` one must write `cc` instead of `CC` in the preamble of `{NiceTabular}` (but there is an option for backward compatibility).